# NAN values when creating dataframe of nested lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a nested list and I make a data frame out of this data frame using this code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

but all the values of the last element of lst (which is a list itself) got jammed in the first cell of its row and all the other cells become NAN.
I made date frames out of nested lists before but I didn't have this problem! Could you please tell me what is happening?

The data frame looks like this:

[image]

Comment: please provide your example in a reproducible format, not an image. Also provide the reproducible form of `lst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely, you have an incorrect nesting level in `lst`.

For example:

```
#                             v       v   extra brackets here
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [[7, 8, 9]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Output:

```
           0    1    2
0          1  2.0  3.0
1          4  5.0  6.0
2  [7, 8, 9]  NaN  NaN
```

You can fix it by unnesting the list:

```
lst2 = [l[0] if isinstance(l[0], list) else l for l in lst]

out = pd.DataFrame(lst2)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```